# Can LDAP recognize password hashes during authentication?

Tags: encryption, ldap

When you authenticate a user against an LDAP server is it possible to send a password hash instead of a plaintext password?

If so, what password hashes does LDAP recognize?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You would need to know a lot of info about LDAP's security internals such as the hashing algorithm and salt (if any) used. These are not the kinds of information that closed systems usually share with the outside world.

Another way to think about is: What would it take for Google or Facebook to recognize a password hashed in another application, and would this be useful?

Comment: Knowing the hash and salt does not alter the security provided by the hash and salt.  This is basic security theory, the only thing you get to hide is the password itself, if someone knows everything except the password they still can't reverse the hash and get the password assuming a properly secure hash algorithm.

Comment: @tloach: I toned down my answer with the security part, but would like to understand your feedback. My assumption was that if a hacker knew the algorithm and salt then a basic dictionary attack would become possible?

Comment: Would it not be possible anyway if someone has access to the LDAP server?  Microsoft doesn't exactly screen potential buyers of Windows Server, do you think someone in the security field (white or black hat) couldn't figure out the hash and salt functions given total control over a server?  If you could monitor the full memory and file system of a computer while adding thousands of users and setting passwords you should be able to get a list of user + password -> hash.  From that, someone better at math than me should be able to get the hash algorithm.

Comment: (continued) A hash provides protection against a reverse-engineering attack.  From the hash there is no simple way to generate the password.  The salt protects from rainbow tables.  A salted hash gives protection in that every password must be brute-forced individually (dictionary attacks are a brute-force method).  While security through obscurity can work for some organizations, Microsoft is simply to large a target to think that their security algorithms will be able to stay secret.